# Programmatically emit a deprecation in older versions for dynamic properties

Tags: php, deprecated

In PHP 8.2, [dynamic properties are deprecated](https://php.watch/versions/8.2/dynamic-properties-deprecated). I am currently developing on PHP 8.1 and would like the code also to work on PHP 8.2.

Near the bottom of the linked page it says:

> It is possible to programmatically emit a deprecation in older versions in the interest of consistency across multiple PHP versions.

Please can anyone explain how to do this? I would like to see a deprecation notice for any use of dynamic properties when developing on PHP 8.1.

I have no idea how, so there's nothing specific that I tried already.

Comment: Good question. Is there any way to contact the author of that article to find out what they're referring to?

Comment: @Barmar Good idea thanks, but how? I don't see any indication of an author.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the magic method [__set](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set) like this:

```
class User
{

    public function __set($name, $value) {
        trigger_error("Deprecated: Creation of dynamic property User::$name is deprecated");
    }

}
```

Because this method is run when writing data to non-existing properties.

By default [trigger_error()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trigger-error.php) generates a warning.

Here's an example: https://3v4l.org/kWbnN

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It's a neat idea, however it would require adding the method to every class in the code, right? I would prefer to avoid that.